# How do I add columns and rows to a Matrix in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, vector, matrix

If I have an existing Matrix in Ruby, how can I add a column or row of new data?

What I want to do is something like this:

```
require 'Matrix'
my_matrix = Matrix.diagonal(1,2,3)
my_matrix.append_row!([3,2,1])
my_matrix.append_column!([3,2,1])
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since doing this isn't (so far as I know) a valid matrix operation in the mathematical sense, there's nothing to do this in place. You can create a new Matrix though:

```
m = Matrix.diagonal(1, 2, 3)
#=> Matrix[[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3]]

Matrix.columns(m.to_a << [4, 5, 6])
#=> Matrix[[1, 0, 0, 4], [0, 2, 0, 5], [0, 0, 3, 6]]

Matrix.rows(m.to_a << [4, 5, 6])
#=> Matrix[[1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

This uses [`columns`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-columns) or [`rows`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-c-rows) to create a new matrix by adding a new array 
to the array representation of the original matrix.

Comment: Small suggestion: The column-adding example works because the matrix is diagonally symmetrical. I believe you'd want `Matrix.columns(m.transpose.to_a << [4,5,6])` to add a column without reordering items.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the methods you are looking for are `[hstack][1]` and `vstack`.